# Magento and decimels in the cart

Tags: magento

I'm changed some functions in magento to strip decimals in price.
The solution appears to work on simple products with no options, but the products with options still display the .00 when the option is chosen. Ironically the drop down for the option displays the additional cost of the option without the decimels, but the main price with the option selected still shows the decimels. Could this be in a js file? configurable.js has reloadOldPrice() method i tried to dump it, but the price var is always 0
any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NEW EDIT**

My previous code won't work indeed. I tested the following and it works:

```
// Wrap original reloadPrice function
spConfig.reloadPrice = spConfig.reloadPrice.wrap(function(original){
    // Call original reloadPrice() function
    original();

    // Get the DOM-element that contains the price
    var priceSpan = $('product-price-'+this.config.productId).down();

    // Get the current value
    var oldP = priceSpan.innerHTML;

    // Change the value
    var newP = oldP.sub('.00','');

    // Update the element
    priceSpan.update(newP);
});
```

In Magento the `spConfig` object defined like `var spConfig = new Product.Config(...);`, so be sure to add the code I give here after instantiation of spConfig.

There is still work to be done:

I'd recommend changing the `var line newP = oldP.sub('.00','');` to something that also catches `,00`, since in some locales that will be the price format.

Furthermore, if you choose to, for example, show prices including **and** excluding tax the code above won't work because `$('product-price-'+this.config.productId).down()` will contain two elements (I think).

If you rather append the code to the `configurable.js` file, you should append it like:

```
Product.Config.prototype.reloadPrice = Product.Config.prototype.reloadPrice.wrap(...);
```

*(notice the `.prototype` which I forgot in my first answer).*

---

**OLD POST (doesn't work)**

*In case people wonder why it doesn't work, first of all it should've been `Product.Config.prototype.formatPrice` instead of `Product.Config.formatPrice` and, secondly, the formatPrice function apparently isn't responsible for how the price html is outputted.*

<strike>`configurable.js` also has a function `formatPrice`, which is probably called when the price is updated.</strike>

So you could try:

```
Product.Config.formatPrice = Product.Config.formatPrice.wrap(function(originalFormatPrice, price, showSign) {
    var str = originalFormatPrice(price, showSign);
    return str.slice(0, -3); // remove last three characters (.00)
});
```

Comment: I made some mistakes, I edited the answer with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Go your price.phtml file**
```

> line no 201

```
<?php echo $_coreHelper->currency($_price, true, true) ?>

replace this code

<?php $_prix = $_coreHelper->currency($_price,true,true) ?>
<?php $_prix = str_replace(".00", "", $_prix); ?>
<?php echo $_prix ?>
```

Comment: in price.phtml $_prix is already without decimels. Decimels appearing when some product option is selected

Comment: find your place add product option for price  where to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use free extension [ET Currency Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html). In this extension this function is realized.